# This tag has no [description]; should it be removed?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

The [description](/questions/tagged/description) tag here on this site seems to have no clear use. It also has no tag wiki description, hence the title.

Looking through the current uses, I see that many of its uses are covered by the tag [wording](/questions/tagged/wording), which does have a clear use. Some of its other uses include Area 51 proposal descriptions and Google search descriptions - things that should be covered by different tags that aren't too broad.

What should we do with the tag? Should we remove it?

Answer (score 3):

If anything, I would suggest synonymizing it with the [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) tag so that way when someone goes to use it in the future it just gets changed to [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) which appears to be a better tag for that use case anyway.

Comment: There are 3 questions that have [both tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wording+description) already.